# Notepad ++ DBGp Debugger plugin not working

Tags: php, windows, iis-7, notepad++, xdebug

i'm already two days trying to configure the notepad ++ DBGp debug plugin and its still not working.
I already search a lot of internet site's but no succes.

My setup is the following:

I have my pc:
with notepad ++ installed on.

and i have a windows server running with iis7 and has the following ip :10.83.A.B

On the windows server i installed Xdebug in the php.ini file:

```
zend_extension = C:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll

[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.5-5.5-VC11-NTS]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=10.83.A.B
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="C:\inetpub\wwwDevelop\logs"
xdebug.idekey=debug
```

if i check phpinfo the Xdebug module is showed.

the DBGp configuration on my laptop in notepad is the following;

```
Remote Server : 10.83.A.B
IDE KEY : debug
Remote Path:\\SERVER-NAME\inetpub\wwwDevelop
Local Path:\\SERVER-NAME\inetpub\wwwDevelop
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, adding in all the following got it working for me. Substituting paths of course. Perhaps you're missing an important one...

```
zend_extension = C:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=default
xdebug.remote_log="D:/www/ourcommunity.dev/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.show_local_vars=9
xdebug.show_mem_delta=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
```